# Firebase unsubscribe to onSnapshot is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to load multiple elements (RoomItem) and each RoomItem has an onSnapshot listener that listens to real-time changes. Now when I change my Workspace which loads a new set of RoomItems, the previous listeners don't unsubscribe and if there's any update in that RoomItem then react renders that list and not the one which should've been there coming from currentWorkspace.

```
  const [roomLiveStatus, setRoomLiveStatus] = useState(false);
  const [unsubscribe, setUnsubscribe] = useState(null);

  const getRoomData = (currentWorkspace) => {
            const {
              roomData,
              workspace,
              allChannels,
              setChannels,
              index,
              currentUser,
            } = props;
        
            const { workspaceId } = workspace;
            const workspaceIdLowerCase = workspaceId.toLowerCase();
        
            const { roomId } = roomData;
            const roomIdLowerCase = roomId.toLowerCase();
        
            const now = new Date().valueOf();
            const query = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`workspaces/${currentWorkspace.workspaceId}/rooms/${roomId}/messages`);
            let unsub;
        
            unsub = query.onSnapshot(
                {
                  includeMetadataChanges: true,
                },
                function (doc) {
                  doc.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                    if (change.type === "added") {
                      if (change.doc.data().timestamp >= now) {
                        console.log("message added ", change.doc.data());
                        let prevAllChannels = allChannels;
                        firebase
                          .firestore()
                          .collection(`workspaces/${currentWorkspace.workspaceId}/rooms/`)
                          .doc(`${roomId}`)
                          .get()
                          .then((doc) => {
                            if (doc.exists) {
                              console.log("updated room data", {
                                ...doc.data(),
                                roomId: doc.id,
                              });
                              prevAllChannels.splice(index, 1, {
                                ...doc.data(),
                                roomId: doc.id,
                                lastMessage: change.doc.data(),
                              });
                              if(currentWorkspace?.workspaceId === workspaceId) {
                                switchSort(prevAllChannels);
                              }
                            }
                          });
                      }
                    }
                    if (change.type === "modified") {
                      console.log("message modified: ", change.doc.data());
                      let prevAllChannels = allChannels;
                      firebase
                        .firestore()
                        .collection(`workspaces/${workspaceId}/rooms/`)
                        .doc(`${roomId}`)
                        .get()
                        .then((doc) => {
                          if (doc.exists) {
                            prevAllChannels.splice(index, 1, {
                              ...doc.data(),
                              roomId: doc.id,
                            });
                            // console.log(prevAllChannels,"prevallchannels",prevSortType,"prevsorttype", props.sortType,"currentsorttype")
                            if(currentWorkspace?.workspaceId === workspaceId) {
                              switchSort(prevAllChannels, props.sortType);
                            }
                          }
                        });
                    }
                    if (change.type === "removed") {
                      console.log("message removed: ", change.doc.data());
                    }
                  });
                }
              );
        
            setUnsubscribe(() => unsub);
       }
        
          useEffect(() => {
            getRoomData(props.currentWorkspace);
          }, []);
        
          useEffect(() => {
            getRoomData(props.currentWorkspace);
          }, [props.sortType, props.currentWorkspace]);
        
          const usePrevious = (value) => {
            const ref = useRef();
            useEffect(() => {
              ref.current = value;
            });
            return ref.current;
          }
        
          const prevCurrentWorkspace = usePrevious(props.currentWorkspace)
        
        
          useEffect(() => {
        
            if(unsubscribe) {
                unsubscribe();
                setUnsubscribe(null);
            }
        
          },[props.workspace, props.currentWorkspace])
        
          useEffect(() => {
            return(() => {
        
                if(unsubscribe)
                unsubscribe()
                setUnsubscribe(null);
        
            })
          },[])
```

Comment: you just copy pasted everything

Comment: can you refine your code and leave only relevant parts, like remove the comments and console logs and everything that doesn't contribute to your question, plus I think you need to create an instance to refer back to it and close its listener but I can't read that cause of all the clutter

Comment: @AKC updated the code.

Comment: I'm already setting the unsub method returned from onSnapshot in the state. And then later on calling it to unsubsribe. Is this not a form of an instance?

Comment: put everything in the useEffect itself.

Comment: Where are you calling your unsub variable to stop listening to changes?